# Can I reverse geocode data with Amazon Kinesis Analytics?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

When using Amazon Kinesis to process a large volume of incoming lat/long data points, what's the best way to reverse geocode these at scale?

Using Kinesis Analytics I can use reference data stored in S3, as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/app-add-reference-data.html

This could contain country & city lat/lng data e.g. from Geonames.

Would it then be possible to run an Analytics query with a haversine formulae to calculate the nearest closest city in my reference table to my lat/lng coordinate data? I could then create an output stream with the enriched reverse geocoded data.

It looks like the SQL engine is missing COS/RADIANS functions however.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, I think a function is pending. For now, you can add a post-processing lambda function and calculate it yourself.

general reference is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/analytics-sql-reference.html